# How to generate a unique random number in a range without repeating a number in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, numbers

I have a requirement to produce a quiz and I need to randomize all numbers but only once between 0 and 24 (25 questions).

For example:

Next 'Question Button' is pressed and it will iterate randomly all 25 numbers until all numbers are used only once. Once it gets to the 25th number, it should go to the 'submit for results' on a last page. I am using C# Multiview to produce the quiz wizard pages but don't quite know how to achieve this efficiently.

So far, I have something like this to generate the numbers, but I don't know the best way to both generate a number and remember that number as the person goes through each page of the quiz to the final number:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine("\n25 random integers from 0 to 24:");
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 25; ctr++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,6}", rnd.Next(0, 24));
            if (ctr % 5 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Generate all numbers, shuffle them, take as many as you need.

Comment: you can this number to a list and check if the number is in the list
not the most efficient way, but it will work

Comment: basically: `Enumerable.Range(0, 25).OrderBy(i => rand.Next()).Take(25)` -- although there are "better" shuffle algorithms (see fisher-yates for example).

Comment: @Corak why would `.Take(25)` even be necessary?

Comment: Yes, I need all 25 unique numbers one time only

Comment: @Rafalon - It's not if one is really interested in *all* the numbers. I kept it in to reflect the previous statement: generate all, shuffle, take.

Comment: The numbers represent the page number to go to which is why I need all numbers

Comment: @Jason - so `Enumerable.Range(0, 25).OrderBy(i => rand.Next())` would suffice, as it produces all the numbers.

Comment: Was a typo. Sorry -- I fixed it.